# view GCM push notifications

Tags: php, google-cloud-messaging

I have used a code to send push notifications using PHP to an android device via GCM. I completed the server side scripting. Before completing the android scripting involved, I would like to know if I will be able to view the notifications by logging into my GCM account. I tried to view it after push, but couldn't. Please help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Just check the return codes or the device you're sending it too. I don't think it is accessible from a web interface of some sort.

Comment: I am an SAP ABAP developer. This is for an SAP mobile integration requirement. So I have very limited knowledge in android coding. According to what I understood, the push notifications are sent from the PHP server into the GCM server. The sending of the notifications to the devices takes place next. I wanted to see if the notifications are reaching the GCM server by logging into my GCM account. Are you saying that this is not possible ?

Comment: Google GCM is best effort. you send your request to google to forward to the devices. Google will attempt to do so for a few weeks or so, the end. There is no confirmation or counter that keeps track of the state of the messages.

Comment: Thanks for your help EWit.. I read that I won't be able to see the notifications in API console page. I will have to login to google pay developer console to view this. That is to be done with a premium membership. I am not buying a premium membership for this test purpose. I will complete the android part and try to view in the device. Your help is appreciated.. :)